# Is it a safe to hardcode my secret key in my iOS app?

Tags: authentication, digital-signature, vulnerability, client, secret-sharing

[Cloudinary iOS SDK configuration](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_ios#configuration) suggests to hardcode your `api_secret` in your iOS app's source code.

Isn't that a security vulnerability since string literals can be extracted from the app binary, e.g., by using the `strings` command?

Neither the [Facebook SDK for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios) nor the [AWS Mobile SDK for iOS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/) asks you to hardcode your API secret into your iOS app's source code. To authenticate client requests, the Facebook SDK for iOS seems to use some sort of signing algorithm and the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS uses [pre-signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) & [Amazon Cognito Identity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/cognito-auth.html).

Comment: You just answered your own question. No, it is not safe to hardcode key's in any application.

Answer (score 2):

The `API-SECRET` as the name implies is secret and therefore should never be revealed in the client-side (nor on mobile applications).

This credential is being used for generating signatures which can then be used for listing, deleting, overwriting and editing your content.

You should either store it on the server side and pass only the generated signature, or use client-side unsigned methods which don't require signatures.